# Comparing decimals consistently with its scale

Tags: c#, nhibernate, cts

I've got two decimal to compare. One comes form a db table mapped with NHibernate with `precision=22` and `scale = 8`, let see an example value as I can see it in the watch:

```
77.47234902
```

the one that I'm comparing with is:

```
77.472349025229
```

of course strict equality fails. I know I can check if the difference being under a certain epsilon, I'm just asking since precision and scale are first citizen in the decimal representation, if there is a smartest way to do such a comparison.

**EDIT**
Just elaborating the @V4Vendetta reply I created this extension method:

```
    public static class ScaleComparer
    {
        public static bool ScaleEquals(this decimal lhs, decimal rhs, int scale)
        {
            decimal mult = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, scale);
            return decimal.Truncate(lhs * mult) / mult == decimal.Truncate(rhs*mult)/mult;
        }
    }
```

It works, but I really feel there'shoud be something smarter :)

Comment: After giving it a little thought I still think `a - b < epsilon` is the smartest/fastest, any "internal" function would probably use the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try on these lines (not sure if smartest)

```
bool iscompared = decimal.Truncate(77.472349025229M * 100000000.0M) / 100000000.0M == 77.47234902M;
```

return `true`

Comment: will elaborate it just to take it configurable, but is the only way till now, thanks !